# Zabbix item key is unsupported for some servers, but not for others

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

My Zabbix instance has basic item keys that are returning "Unsupported Key item: for some servers, but not for others. The one key that sticks out:

```
Name          Key                    Type       
NTP running?  net.udp.service[ntp]   Zabbix Agent(active)
```

Of course, when I ssh to the server, ntp is running. Is there a way to find out why exactly it is not supported?

Zabbix Agents are Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 Zabbix 3.4
Zabbix Server is Ubuntu 16.04 and Zabbix 3.4

Comment: What are the exact agent versions on systems where this works and on systems where this fails? Is it just this key that's the issue, or are there other identifiable keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the comment was eluding to, the root cause was, in fact, the version numbers.  The zabbix server was v3.4, however the agents were actually 2.x, which does not support this key.  Once upgraded to v3.4.1, the problem was solved.